# Problems using boost::asio::async_read()

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Here's the code I use:

```
class Server
{
.....

void Server::accepted()
{
    std::cout << "Accepted!" << std::endl;

    boost::array<char, 1> buf;
    boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buf),
        boost::bind(&Server::handleRead, this, buf, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void Server::handleRead(boost::array<char, 1> buf, const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if(!error)
    {
        std::cout << "Message: " << buf.data() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error occurred." << std::endl;
    }
}

.....
}
```

The problem is that I always get the same data from the client: a specific char.
In my client I tried sending other char, but still the server shows the same char.

And when I try to read more than 1 bytes, I get an error that the `buf` variable is used before it's initialized.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using the local variable `buf` as the read buffer, which is dangerous and won't work. Also, you're just sending the original contents of that buffer to the handler. So instead, you need to use a buffer with a longer lifetime. Something like this:

```
class Server
{
.....

boost::array<char, 1> buf;

void Server::accepted()
{
    std::cout << "Accepted!" << std::endl;

    boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buf),
        boost::bind(&Server::handleRead, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void Server::handleRead(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if(!error)
    {
        std::cout << "Message: " << buf.data() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error occurred." << std::endl;
    }
}

.....
}
```

**edit**: or alternatively, using a heap allocated buffer (not sure if the code is right, but you'll get the idea):

```
void Server::accepted()
{
    std::cout << "Accepted!" << std::endl;

    boost::shared_ptr<boost::array<char, 1>> buf(new boost::array<char, 1>);

    boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(*buf),
        boost::bind(&Server::handleRead, this, buf, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void Server::handleRead(boost::shared_ptr<boost::array<char, 1>> buf, const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if(!error)
    {
        std::cout << "Message: " << buf->data() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error occurred." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 when using asynchronous methods, it is the caller's responsibility to ensure the buffer is valid throughout the lifetime of the call.

Comment: Thanks it works, but with a little problem. I configured the client to send "aaaaaa" and the server to read 6 characters. The server is successfully reading the characters but not cleanly: "Message: aaaaaaÌÌÌÌÌÌ(c².ˆ÷0". This is the output I see in the server's console. I've also tried to write buf.data() into a file, but still the same output.

Comment: That is because the string isn't null terminated. So you need to use a 7 character buffer, and either have the client send a null terminated string or have the server set the 7th character to null manually. Or you could use std::string as the buffer, just remember to call .resize(6) before you use it.

Comment: So the last problem wasn't related to boost::asio :) thanks, it works great.